# SetTokenInformation fails with 24, but the length is correct

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to create a elevated `SYSTEM` token, but the code below fails:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL Elevate()
{
    PSID pSID = NULL;
    HANDLE hToken = NULL, hToken2 = NULL;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY NtAuthority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;

    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hToken))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "OpenProcessToken(): %d\n", GetLastError());
        goto done;
    }

    if (!DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, &hToken2))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "DuplicateTokenEx(): %d\n", GetLastError());
        goto done;
    }

    if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(
        &NtAuthority,
        1,
        SECURITY_MANDATORY_SYSTEM_RID,
        0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        &pSID))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "AllocateAndInitializeSid(): %d\n", GetLastError());
        goto done;
    }

    if (!SetTokenInformation(hToken2, TokenIntegrityLevel, &pSID, sizeof(pSID)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SetTokenInformation(): %d\n", GetLastError());
        goto done;
    }

done:
    if (pSID)
    {
        FreeSid(pSID);
        pSID = NULL;
    }

    CloseHandle(hToken);
    CloseHandle(hToken2);

    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Elevate();
}
```

It fails on `SetTokenInformation`, and the error code is 24: `ERROR_BAD_LENGTH`. Does anyone know what's wrong?

**EDIT**

Remy Lebeau was right, and I found an example here: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/WIN02-C.+Restrict+privileges+when+spawning+child+processes

Comment: `pSID` is a pointer, so `sizeof(pSID)` will always return the size of pointer (either 32 or 64-bit). The expected value of the last argument is different: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-settokeninformation

Comment: Follow up on the above comment, try passing `sizeof(SID)` instead of `sizeof(pSID)`. I am on mac, so have not tested it though

Comment: Thanks @Asesh, I've tried sizeof(SID) and GetLastError() still returns 24

Comment: @Asesh Regardless of the underlying issue with the code shown (passing the wrong data to `SetTokenInformation()`), this feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) to me. What exactly are you planning on using this "elevated" token for? There is likely to be a better solution. Allowing any arbitrary process to gain elevated SYSTEM access is a major security risk.

Comment: in example also was error `sizeof(tml) + GetLengthSid(psd)` when must be exactly `sizeof(tml)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [`TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ne-winnt-token_information_class) documentation

> `TokenIntegrityLevel`
> The buffer receives a [`TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-token_mandatory_label) structure that specifies the token's integrity level.

Where `TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL` is defined as:

```
typedef struct _SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES {
#if ...
  PISID Sid;
#else
  PSID  Sid;
#endif
  DWORD Attributes;
} SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES, *PSID_AND_ATTRIBUTES;

typedef struct _TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL {
  SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Label;
} TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL, *PTOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL;
```

So, you need to give `SetTokenInformation()` a pointer to a `TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL`, not a pointer to a `SID`, eg:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL Elevate()
{
    TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL tml = {};
    HANDLE hToken = NULL, hToken2 = NULL;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY NtAuthority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
    BOOL result = FALSE;

    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hToken))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "OpenProcessToken(): %ul\n", GetLastError());
        goto done;
    }

    if (!DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, &hToken2))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "DuplicateTokenEx(): %ul\n", GetLastError());
        goto done;
    }

    if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(
        &NtAuthority,
        1,
        SECURITY_MANDATORY_SYSTEM_RID,
        0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        &(tml.Label.SID)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "AllocateAndInitializeSid(): %ul\n", GetLastError());
        goto done;
    }

    tml.Label.Attributes = ...; // desired integrity level

    if (!SetTokenInformation(hToken2, TokenIntegrityLevel, &tml, sizeof(tml)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SetTokenInformation(): %ul\n", GetLastError());
        goto done;
    }

    result = TRUE;

done:
    if (tml.Label.SID) FreeSid(tml.Label.SID);
    if (hToken) CloseHandle(hToken);
    if (hToken2) CloseHandle(hToken2);

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Elevate();
}
```